# MD5 PHP bad result

Tags: php

I tried to generate hash `MD5` for online payment processing and i'm getting hash invalid .

I found out that the `MD5` function generates different results but I do not know why.

This is my part of code:

```
 $tmp="330012345211.0024-01-2014:13:07:47:357newsecret";
   $ab= md5($tmp);

$terminalid=33001;
    $orderid=23452;
    $amount=11.00;
    $datetime=0024-01-2014:13:07:47:357;
    $secret=newsecret;

  $tmp1="$terminalid"."$orderid"."$amount"."$datetime"."$secret";
    $aa=md5($tmp1);
```

Why is the result from `$aa` different than `$ab` ?

Comment: One of the causes could be coming from `$datetime=0024-01-2014:13:07:47:357;` since it's probably trying to do a mathematical equation. Set it inside of quotes.

Comment: Perhaps the missing `$` on `newsecret` is causing it to be left out, causing the md5 tobe wrong?

Comment: Sidenote: I don't know if you're using `md5` has anything to do with password storage. IF it does, then I suggest that you don't use `md5`, it's 1996 technology.

Comment: As an aside, when directly concatenating variables, you don't need quotes around them separately. `$tmp1=$terminalid . $orderid . $amount . $datetime . $secret;` would suffice. (Spaces not required.)

Answer (score 3):

```
$secret=newsecret;
```

In `$ab`, `newsecret` is a string.

In `$aa`, `newsecret` is being used as a constant because it's not enclosed in quotes. I presume you have not defined this as a constant, so add quotes.

```
$secret='newsecret';
```

---

Actually, none of your strings are enclosed in quotes.

```
$terminalid='33001';
$orderid='23452';
$amount='11.00';
$datetime='0024-01-2014:13:07:47:357';
$secret='newsecret';
```

(I'm enclosing the numbers in quotes, too, because IDs/numbers could begin with a `0` or end in `.0`, which would likely be dropped when a number is implicitly typecast to a string.)

---

One other thing I noticed: you probably mistakenly copied the "00" at the start of `$datetime`. Otherwise in `$aa` you'll get "...11.000024..." instead of "...11.0024..." as in `$ab`. Should probably be:

```
$datetime='24-01-2014:13:07:47:357';
```

Comment: Having `$datetime=0024-01-2014:13:07:47:357;` unquoted, has nothing to do with it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ha, that too.

Comment: I had posted it as a comment under the OP's question, seemed like it was set as doing a math equation @Wiseguy

Comment: @Fred-ii- In all likelihood, it would cause an error because the colons won't make sense.

Comment: True; that's another thing that made me raise a brow. @Wiseguy